# Does Npoi library support i18n for numbers and dates ?

Tags: internationalization, npoi

Suppose I have a number - 1000.65 . I want this to be downloaded in Italian number format as - 1.000,65

Dont want to convert it to string while formatting.

Comment: I don't understand your question.  What does downloading have to do with Npoi?  Npoi is for reading and writing Excel spreadsheets.  Can you add more details to explain exactly what you're trying to do?